# Evaluate Like Records

Tags: sql

how can I update 1 record based on some field?  I've already created a cursor to loop through records with the same ID, but I need to update the activeFlag for the record with the most current startDate.

```
someID  startDate    endDate      activeFlag
6       2011-07-25   9999-12-31   0
6       2013-09-22   9999-12-31   0
```

in this example, I want to set activeFlag=1 for the record with a startDate of 09.22.2013

Comment: perform an update on the activeflag field where startdate = @cursorvariableholdingtheStartDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you order by the `startDate` you can limit the update to the first record

```
update your_table
set activeFlag = 1
order by startDate desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your criteria correctly, you can use an update query with a sub query to grab the latest (or maximum) start date value.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET activeFlag = 1
WHERE startDate = (SELECT MAX(startDate) FROM myTable);
```

However, if there are multiple rows with the same startDate, they'll all get updated. You could apply a `LIMIT 1` if you only need only 1 record updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
update X set activeFlag = 1 where startDate = (select max(startDate) from X)
```

ps. this may update more than just one row of course